# Dokku different apps but same Vhost

Tags: virtualhost, docker

I am just get a dedicated server and i would like to setup a dokku configuration.

I bought a domain name and i would like my different application in different dokku: apps but with the same domain name but different vhost like :

- resume.mywebsite.com    // for my resume page
- git.mywebsite.com // for my git lab
- anyotherapp.mywebsite.com ...

Is it nice to do it with dokku ? or is it better to use only docker ?! How do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each application automatically gets it's own domain name based upon the initial domain you set, and you can go back and add/remove domain names as a later date. I encourage you to read the documentation surrounding application deployment and domain management, as it will answer a lot of your questions.